# Birt Runtime Libraries with Tomcat startup slow

Tags: java, tomcat, birt

When I start my tomcat takes between 10 and 20 minutes. I have:

1. **Apache-tomcat-7.0.53**
2. **Birt-runtime-3_7_1**: I put the JARs from **birt-runtime-3_7_1\ReportEngine\lib** to **Apache-tomcat-7.0.53\lib**, are 78 JARs!!

I know that put 78 JARS is very crazy but I can not found other alternative. If I do not put the JARs, I get errors like 'ClassNotFoundException'.

Is there anyway to add some JARs, How do I know which libraries are?.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to check your JVM behaviour by e.g. enabling verboseGC. You might have to optimize JVM parameters...

Comment: I checked my JVM settings but I am sure that is not the problem, because if I remove the Birt Libraries from my **tomcat\lib**, this start in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: What is the size of the permanent memory of the JVM (maxpermsize)? And the max size of the heap memory?

Comment: **-XX:MaxPermSize=512M and -Xmx512m**.
I moved the **JARs** to my WEB-INF\LIB\ and the server starts perfectly, i don't know what happened but for now i will use this trick.

Comment: Try using wait tool to see what virtual machine is doing at that time: https://wait.ibm.com/. Once you do it, just provide the link to the report.

Comment: Memory setup seems fine. When we install an Eclipse Birt webviewer on a fresh Tomcat, Tomcat still starts very fastly so the problem is probably not related to JARs themselves. May be there is a conflict due to the fact you put them in a shared library, you could try to move all birt jars in WEB-INF/lib folder of the webapp which makes use of the birt runtime.